# How to restore Mongo DB tar.gz archive

Tags: mongodb, mongo-repair, mongorestore

Using the Mongo DB Atlas cloud service (MongoDB Version: 3.4.16), the below backup archive of a MongDB was generated:

Cluster0-shard-0-1531635127-5b4b0df33b34b92b0f50a045.tar.gz

In this file I can see the collections:

```
collections-0--****.wt
```

How can this DB be fully restored on a local instance of MongoDB?

Local MongoDB version is 3.4.16

Edit: 
Thanks for pointing to editing dbPath config, I was now able to make some progress by putting the files in C:\data\db and downgrading to 3.4. (Although I would rather have the files on the D: drive). Unfortunately now the new error with mongod.exe is:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin    mongod
2018-09-03T11:01:16.380-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=16920 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=DESKTOP-3SH9864
2018-09-03T11:01:16.380-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2018-09-03T11:01:16.380-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.16
2018-09-03T11:01:16.380-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 0d6a9242c11b99ddadcfb6e86a850b6ba487530a
2018-09-03T11:01:16.380-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2o-fips  27 Mar 2018
2018-09-03T11:01:16.380-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-09-03T11:01:16.380-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-09-03T11:01:16.380-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-09-03T11:01:16.380-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2018-09-03T11:01:16.380-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-09-03T11:01:16.380-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-09-03T11:01:16.380-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2018-09-03T11:01:16.381-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:\data\db\ created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-09-03T11:01:16.381-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7615M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-09-03T11:01:16.395-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1535997676:395795][16920:140715718360144], txn-recover: unsupported WiredTiger file version: this build  only supports major/minor versions up to 1/0,  and the file is version 3/0: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2018-09-03T11:01:16.395-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1535997676:395795][16920:140715718360144], txn-recover: WiredTiger is unable to read the recovery log.
2018-09-03T11:01:16.396-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1535997676:395795][16920:140715718360144], txn-recover: This may be due to the log files being encrypted, being from an older version or due to corruption on disk
2018-09-03T11:01:16.396-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1535997676:395795][16920:140715718360144], txn-recover: You should confirm that you have opened the database with the correct options including all encryption and compression options
2018-09-03T11:01:16.396-0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1535997676:395795][16920:140715718360144], txn-recover: Recovery failed: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
2018-09-03T11:01:16.398-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:-31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error src\mongo\db\storage\wiredtiger\wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 277
2018-09-03T11:01:16.399-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 -31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error, terminating
2018-09-03T11:01:16.399-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2018-09-03T11:01:16.399-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2018-09-03T11:01:16.399-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-09-03T11:01:16.399-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

with mongo.exe the error is different:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin> mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.16
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-09-03T19:02:26.926+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2018-09-03T19:02:26.926+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:240:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Edit: added MongoDB version of backup file as found in restoreinfo.txt

Comment: What version of MongoDB is your Atlas deployment using? What is your local O/S version and install method for MongoDB? In general the backup archive just needs to be unpacked into a new directory which you specify as the [`dbPath`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath) for your local deployment. To ensure data file compatibility the major version of your local MongoDB server should ideally be the same as your Atlas deployment (for example, both 4.0.x).

Comment: Can you confirm the MongoDB version on your Atlas deployment? It looks like your backup is for a newer version of MongoDB than you have installed locally.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to delete the below files in data folder:

- delete folder: `data/db/journal`
- delete file: `mongod.lock`
- delete file `WiredTiger.lock`

After doing this, I could start mongod without any issues.

Comment: Welcome on the Unix SE! I think it is better, if you also explain (or, at least, try to explain) the possible reasons of the behavior, only writing what to do is not very good.